# Why is it possible to get this enum member value without having to delve in the nested enum first?

Tags: c++, enums

(under Visual Studio 2012)

Consider the following class :

```
class pe_exception : public std::runtime_error
{
public:
    //Exception IDs
    enum exception_id
    {
        unknown_error,
        bad_pe_file,
        bad_dos_header,
        image_nt_headers_not_found,
        error_reading_image_nt_headers,
        error_reading_data_directories,
        error_reading_file,
        pe_signature_incorrect,
...
```

Can you tell why is it possible to directly get the enum member with such code :

```
bool b = e.get_id() == pe_exception::error_reading_image_nt_headers;
```

Instead of having to go into the enum first ?

```
bool b = e.get_id() == pe_exception::exception_id::error_reading_image_nt_headers;
```

(library where this is taken from : https://code.google.com/p/portable-executable-library/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is just the way old-school enums work: they have no scope. This comes directly from C.

For example:

```
enum Colour { red, black, orange };
Colour c = orange; // OK

enum Fruit { banana, apple, orange }; // ERROR: orange has already been defined
```

C++11 class enums or scoped enumerations fix this (see [*scoped enumerations* here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) for more information).

```
enum class Colour { red, black, orange };
Colour c = orange;     // ERROR
Colour c = Color::red; // OK

enum class Fruit { banana, apple, orange }; // OK
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is absolutly equivalent to a list of static int declaration, except the compiler generates initialization value starting at 0, and incrementing by one between each value.

In your case

```
enum exception_id
{
    unknown_error,
    bad_pe_file,
    bad_dos_header
};
int val = exception_id::unknown_error; //Not ok (except >MSVC 2010)
```

Note that on visual since VS 2010 (maybe before) you can add the nested scope to be more precise, but that was not standard (and not compiling on GCC and CLang).

is equivalent to:

```
static int unknown_error = 0;
static int bad_pe_file= 1;
static int bad_dos_header= 2;
```

The solution before C++11 was

```
struct exception_id{
enum exception_id_enum
{
    unknown_error,
    bad_pe_file,
    bad_dos_header
};};

int val = exception_id::unknown_error; //ok
```

Now you can write

```
enum class exception_id{
{
    unknown_error,
    bad_pe_file,
    bad_dos_header
};

auto val = exception_id::unknown_error; //ok
```

Last but very important point The typing changes, now you have strong typing on this.
I let you read the FAQ of [bjarne](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum)

See here a nice explaination on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cskb49.aspx)